# Require one field or the other but CANNOT be left blank -- Image or Radio Option

Tags: jquery

I am looking for the following functionality:

The user is required to fill in either one of two fields to be able to submit.

One field is an Image Upload. The other field is a radio dropdown list. I want it set so that in order to submit the form, ONE of these options must be chosen but NOT both and BOTH cannot be blank.

How can do I possibly do this through jquery? Forgive me as I am relatively new to jquery and am still learning.

I was thinking along the lines of the validate function but any way to get my desired result would be nice.

Comment: You should never rely on client-side validation. You can use server-side validation or client-side + server-side, but never client-side alone.

Comment: +1 Fully agreed on client-side validation alone. Assuming you validate properly server-side (at least), see answer for a way to encourage good results from your visitors.

Comment: I already have server-side validation. Thanks for the concern though haha. It be nice to have a prevention through client side though

Comment: @wiseman7687 In this case see my comment to sscirrus' answer. You cannot validate file inputs client side. You would need to use some third-party library that relies on Flash (like Uploadify) to be able to check if user selected a file.

Comment: Hmm ok, Well I am validating if it is uploaded or radio selected through PHP but it would be nice to have a check before the form is submitted. I will look into Uploadify to see if that is a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good way to do this would be to give the user a choice by allowing him/her to click one of two buttons - you would then use JQuery to reveal/hide the right option based on the option they picked. This means only one option is visible at any time. This has these advantages:

1. The user cannot as easily fill in both options (it's less likely the user will get confused/frustrated if they do twice the work and the system rejects it).
2. If the user doesn't have JS the browser will just display both options with a notice (see my example).
3. The Jquery is nice and simple and it won't break as easily on IE/non-mainstream browsers.

Here's how I would do it (untested but should work).

```
# view
<button type="button" id="choose_image">Upload an image</button>
<button type="button" id="choose_radio">Choose from list</button>
<div id="noJS">
  Please only complete ONE of these two options.
</div>
<div id="image">
   ...
</div>
<div id="radio">
  ...
</div>

# Jquery
$(document).onload( function(){
  $('#noJS').hide();
  $('#radio').hide();
})
$('#choose_image').click( function(){
  $('#radio').hide(); // or slideToggle() or fadeOut() etc.
  $('#image').show();
});
$('#choose_radio').click( function(){
  $('#radio').show();
  $('#image').hide();
});
```

In general, there are a few considerations here in whatever approach you choose:

1. What is the clearest system for a user who might be new/rushing/not paying attention?
2. What is least likely to cause frustration, especially by making a user do work that you later reject? (Solution: engineer it to naturally incur the result you want.)
3. What is the most accessible to the most people in your target audience?

Comment: Regardless of logic surrounding it, you cannot validate image upload client side, unless he uses some kind of upload library like Uploadify, which isn't in scope of this question.

Comment: This does not seem like a bad idea. I can't get it to replicate the effect though. Are there any important lines I am missing?

Comment: @wiseman7687 - it should work as far as I can see. Make sure you've got Jquery loaded.

Comment: @liho1eye - the OP did not specify whether he meant validating the presence of an attachment vs. validating the type of file. If the former is all that's required, such validation is trivial.